# How to use generic in Class.class

Tags: java, class, reflection

I want to avoid the warning:

"type safety the expression of type needs unchecked conversion to conform to Class"

From this sentence:

```
Class<MyInterface> cc = interpreter.get("Myclass", Class.class );
```

I have tried:

```
Class<MyInterface> cc = interpreter.get("Myclass", Class<MyInterface>.class );
```

But is invalid.

How can I do that without @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

The signature of interpreter.get:

```
T interpreter.get(String name, Class<T> javaClass)
```

---

The context:
I use the library Jython and I define a class in Python who implement MyInterface, then I capture this class in Java then I create instances of them. That is why I need the class itself, not a instance of the class.

The code is something like:

```
PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
interpreter.exec("from cl.doman.python import MyInterface");
....
interpreter.exec(pythonCode);
Class<MyInterface> cc = interpreter.get("Myclass", Class.class);
MyInterface a = (MyInterface) cc.newInstance();
```

My code work fine But I can't suppress the warning.

Comment: whats inside interpreter.get().. whats the method signature like?

Comment: That is not returning a `Class<MyInterface>`, that's returning a `MyInterface`.

Comment: "sethu": I update the question

Comment: I think you want `MyInterface cc = in.get("Myclass", MyInterface.class);`

Comment: Thilo:  yes,  your  line is perfect but y I need "Class<MyInterface>" not "MyInterface"

Comment: @Troncador, why do you think you need `Class<MyInterface>`? Please provide the body of `interpreter.get` method if possible.

Comment: You can't. There's no such thing as a `Class<Class<MyInterface>>` because `Class<MyInterface>` is not a class. Are you allowed to change the signature of `interpreter.get`?

Comment: "immibis": no, I can't change is from de libray jython

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably

```
Class<?> clazz = interpreter.get("Myclass", Class.class); 
Class<? extends MyInterface> cc = clazz.asSubclass(MyInterface.class);
// look, Ma, no typecast!
MyInterface a = cc.newInstance();
```

Comment: You may have the "rawtypes" warning unless you cast explicitly: `((Class<?>) interpreter.get("Myclass", Class.class)).asSubclass(MyInterface.class);`

Comment: this solution can't avoid the warning from " interpreter.get("Myclass", Class.class)" it make 2 warning :S

Comment: humn... but is a very good avoid the cast  (MyInterface) :P, thanks

Comment: It should work with another variable: `Class<?> clazz=interpreter.get("Myclass", Class.class); Class<? extends MyInterface> cc = clazz.asSubclass(MyInterface.class); MyInterface a = cc.newInstance();` without any compiler warnings.

Comment: Holger: that exactly what I want!! please put your comment in a answer

Answer (score -1):

**Update** Given the new context of the question (the use of PythonInterpreter), the contents of my answer would be for a generic `T get(String name, Class<T> javaClass)` and not for use with the PythonInterpreter.

I wrote a small example along with a simple "Interpreter" class that defines a simple method per your example. Given your example get method. I would expect it to return `T` and not `Class<T>`.

The below example also reminds me of a (very simple) example of Spring Bean loading where you may load a concrete implementation and return the interface.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Interperter<MyInterface> interperter = new Interperter<MyInterface>() ;
        final MyInterface i = interperter.get("MyClass", MyInterface.class);
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    public static class Interperter<T> {
        // A sample get method with the same signature, The body's contents shouldn't matter to much for this demonstration.
        public T get(String name, Class<T> javaClass) {
            try {
                final Class<?> clazz = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass(name);
                return (T) clazz.newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

A sample Interface

```
public interface MyInterface {}
```

A sample Base Class

```
public final class MyClass implements MyInterface {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyClass{}";
    }
}
```

The programs output: `MyClass{}`

Let me know if you feel that I misunderstood your question :)

Comment: Could someone explain the -1? By the signature of `T get(String name, Class<T> javaClass) `, he can't get what he wants.

Comment: I want a object of type Class<MyInterface> no of the type Myinterface (sorry for the -1, is not my fault)

Comment: No problem! I was not aware you were using the PythonInterpreter at first since you only defined the signature in the original question. My answer was limited to only knowing that. (In which case it was impossible by using that method alone).